# How to centering gridview on load and scroll left and right to see all columns?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview, centering

I have a gridview which has a lot of columns. On page load, I want to see the center column on page and scroll left and right to see all data. Is there a way to do that?

I tried

`display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: auto;`

that CSS code.It centered but I lost first columns I could not scroll left to see them.

Answer (score 0):

It will let the grid view flow in x region

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;width:800px">

<asp:gridview ... </asp:gridview> 

</div>
```

Put your Page width.

Comment: sorry it did not work! still, I can not scroll left

Comment: Try using a TableLayout inside a HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: I'm using Gridview